# What is causing this error in changing the default music font in a Lilypond document?

Tags: fonts, lilypond

The first few lines of my file `clarinettrio.ly` look like this (with several lines of comments removed for your convenience):

```
\version "2.18.0"

\paper {
    #(define fonts
     (set-global-fonts
        #:music "Improviso" 
    ))  
}
```

Unfortunately, attempting to run Lilypond results in this (relatively uninformative) error:

```
C:/MusicStuff/COMPOSITION/PORTFOLIO/Clarinet Trio/clarinettrio.ly:27:4: error: GUILE signaled an error for the expression beginning here
    #
       (define fonts
```

I checked multiple times to make sure I followed the examples I found online, so if you know what I might be doing wrong, any help would be appreciated!

(I found a forum online where a similar problem was being discussed, but in that instance, the error message included something about undefined variables, which ended up being the problem. The error message I'm getting does not include anything about variables, which makes sense since at that point in the file, no variables have been defined yet.)

The problem persists if I replace `"Improviso"` with `"emmentaler"` or `"feta"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [openlilylib website](http://fonts.openlilylib.org/), where you probably downloaded the Improviso font, you must use lilypond version 2.19.12 or later.
Also, be sure to copy the Improviso font inside the lilypond install directory. I suggest using [this script](https://github.com/openlilylib/openlilylib/tree/master/fonts).

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I had the feeling it was going to be something obvious and facepalm-worthy. Would you recommend patching 2.18.2 (the latest stable) or just installing 2.19.15 (the latest unstable dev version)?

Comment: It's up to you and it depends on the project you are working on. Using stable versions is usually recommended but testing new development versions is a good way to test the future stable and help lilypond developers. I have both installed and use stable or unstable depending on the project.

Answer (score 0):

The Improviso font for Lilypond is available as a [lyp](http://lyp.noteflakes.com/) package, which takes care of installing it. You can use the font on any version of Lilypond from 2.18.2 on without any patching or copying of files.

```
$ gem install lyp
$ lyp install lilypond
$ lyp install improviso
```

To use the font in your score file:

```
\require "improviso"
\useImprovisoStyleSheet
```

The [improviso](https://github.com/lyp-packages/improviso) package includes complementary text fonts and some usage examples.